# How to scroll a button on page scroll

Tags: javascript

I need to know how to scroll a button on page scroll.

I have some 200 table data where I can select anyone of them, and then I can submit it to a database. The problem is, if I select the 1st row of table data I need to travel toward the bottom of the table to bring the submit button into view.  I am planning to make the button scroll with the page, can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: <div style="height:500px;overflow:auto">  //All rows here  </div>  <input type="submit">  this looks bit odd i need automatic scroll when my page scroll down and up

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is make your table scrollable

put the whole data inside the `<div>` and make it scrollable and put the submit button outside this div.
something like:-

```
<div style="height:500px;overflow:auto">
//All rows here
</div>
<input type="submit">
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks its working fine but it looks bit odd in my page,can we do page scroll with button movements parallely

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed` in your css:

```
#myButtonId {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didnt get your question right. Did you mean that the submit button should be stationary irrespective of the page scroll. if it's so, add 'position: absolute' style to the button and add 'top', 'left' values to the css.

Answer (score 0):

Istead of using javascript or position:absolute css, consider adding one button/link to each row, called "Choose this row" or similar.